# SQL Another ALIAS of same table that has been joined without join again

Tags: sql

My query has already worked but it always timeout when the data has become too big.

How can I optimize it?

```
SELECT CONCAT(BRANCHORIGIN.name, ' to ', BRANCH.name) AS "Branch Transfer"
FROM office AS OFFICE
LEFT JOIN branch AS BRANCH ON OFFICE.branch_id = BRANCH.id
LEFT JOIN branch AS BRANCHORIGIN ON OFFICE.branch_id_origin = BRANCHORIGIN.id
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us table and index definitions. And the explain output/execution plan.

Comment: Two close votes (none mine) already. You'd better hurry up and add the information asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try + operator instead of concat. Here is an article about concat vs + comparison. Please tell us if its work or not

https://stevestedman.com/2021/01/performance-string-concatenation-in-sql-server/

SELECT BRANCHORIGIN.name + ' to '+ BRANCH.name AS "Branch Transfer"

Comment: How do you know OP is using MS SQL Server?

Comment: i don't know just feel :).